# How can a SearchBar search through a NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `NSMutableArray` and I'm trying to create a search bar. I have been looking for hours and I can't find anything that really helps me because I'm using the `NSMutableArray` with Firebase. I'm kinda new to Swift. I have created a table view and a search bar. The table view is showing data from the `NSMutableArray`. How can I make it so when the user is searching on the search bar then the whole post comes up?

If there is a post that contains 2 Strings and an image and one String is "A City" and the other String is the title of the post, and let's say that when the user is searching only for the title of the post or only the city, then the entire post shows. If the result could be on the same `viewcontroller` like on the same `tableview`.

I have written this so far in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
func setUpSearchBar() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

And my array is like this:

```
var posts = NSMutableArray()
```

The only thing really that I have written is so that the search bar is setup but not really functional because I have not found anything that could help me and since I'm new to this is not either sure how to make the search bar work at all. All the tutorials I have to find so far is very normal arrays like:

```
var post = ["pear", "orange", "apple"]
```

But I cant find on how to make the search iterate through my post `NSMutableArray`.

I would be really happy if anyone could possibly help me through this. I don't want straight answers if possible with some explanation so I can learn this and create this myself.

this is the code that downloads the data and displays it in the `TableView`

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var postsTableView: UITableView!

var posts = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpSearchBar()
    loadData()

    self.postsTableView.delegate = self
    self.postsTableView.dataSource = self

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func loadData() {

    Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "timeorder").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for post in postsDictionary {
                self.posts.add(post.value)

            }
            self.postsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}




// MARK: - Table view data source

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
         return self.posts.count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
    cell.titleLabel.text = post["title"] as? String
    cell.contentTextView.text = post["content"] as? String
    cell.dateAndTimeLabel.text = post["time"] as? String
    cell.usernameLabel.text = post["username"] as? String
    cell.locationAdressLabel.text = post["adress"] as? String

        if let imageName = post["image"] as? String {

            let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageName)")
            imageRef.getData(maxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    //successfull
                    let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                    cell.postsImageView.image = downloadedImage
                }else {
                    // error

                    print("there was an error downloading image: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }
    }

            return cell
        }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 500.0
}

@IBAction func goToProfilePage(_ sender: Any) {
    let logoutSuccess = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC")
    self.present(logoutSuccess!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func navigateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let navigate = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigateVC")
    self.present(navigate!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func chooseCountry(_ sender: Any) {
    let navigate = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CountryVC")
    self.present(navigate!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func setUpSearchBar() {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    definesPresentationContext = true



}
```

And Here is The Code That uploads the `post` to Firebase

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class PostViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var addImageButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var pickCountryPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var choosenCountryLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var contentTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var locationAdressTextField: UITextField!


var imageFileName = ""

var timeStamps = ""
var secondTimeStamps = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let currentDateTime = Date()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

    timeStamps = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDateTime))"

    let secondDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    secondDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00"

    secondTimeStamps = "\(secondDateFormatter.string(from: currentDateTime))"

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func postButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if (self.imageFileName != "") {
        if choosenCountryLabel.text == "Afghanistan" {
        // image has finshed the uploading, Saving Post!!!
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    for user in userDictionary{
                        if let username = user.value as? String {
                            if let streetAdress = self.locationAdressTextField.text {
                                if let title = self.titleTextField.text {
                                    if let content = self.contentTextView.text {
                                        let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                                            "uid" : uid,
                                            "title" : title,
                                            "content" : content,
                                            "username" : username,
                                            "time" : self.timeStamps,
                                            "timeorder" : self.secondTimeStamps,
                                            "image" : self.imageFileName,
                                            "adress" : streetAdress
                                        ]

                                        Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)
                                        Database.database().reference().child("Afghanistanposts").childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)
                                        Database.database().reference().child(uid).childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)

                                        let alertPosting = UIAlertController(title: "Successfull upload", message: "Your acty was successfully uploaded.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                        alertPosting.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                                            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AfghanistanVC")
                                            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                        }))
                                        self.present(alertPosting, animated: true, completion: nil)



                                        print("Posted Succesfully to Firebase, Saving Post!!!")

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

        }
    }else{
        let alertNotPosting = UIAlertController(title: "Seems like you got connection problems", message: "Your image has not been uploaded. Please Wait 10 seconds and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertNotPosting.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertNotPosting, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 @IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any) {

    if addImageButton.isEnabled == false {
        let alertNotPosting = UIAlertController(title: "Image already Picked", message: "sorry you already have an image picked", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertNotPosting.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertNotPosting, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imageView.image = pickedImage
        uploadImage(image: pickedImage)
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        addImageButton.isEnabled = false

    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func uploadImage(image: UIImage){
    let randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 10)
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    let uploadRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")

    let uploadTask = uploadRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        if error == nil {
            //success
            print("SuccessFully uploaded")
            self.imageFileName = "\(randomName as String).jpg"
        }else {
            // not success =  error

            print("error with the Image: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

        }
    }
}

func randomStringWithLength(length: Int) -> NSString {
    let characters: NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    var randomString: NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: length)

    for i in 0..<length {
        var len = UInt32(characters.length)
        var rand = arc4random_uniform(len)
        randomString.appendFormat("%C", characters.character(at: Int(rand)))

    }
    return randomString
}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return countries[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return countries.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    choosenCountryLabel.text = countries[row]
}

}
```

and below this is a array full of countries for the picker and is not nessecary to show.

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableArray`. It is not related to Swift arrays and you are fighting the strong type system. You get mutability for free just with `var`

Comment: @vadian then what should i use NSArray? or?

Comment: No, use Swift arrays, `[String]` or `[Post]` etc. Don't use `NS...` collection types at all unless the compiler tells you that you need them (for example in a few CoreFoundation function calls and Objective-C bridged inout parameters)

Comment: i think i need the `NSMutableArray` because the post must be changeable sense the `user` username is also in there and if the user changes it´s username then it must change in the post aswell @vadian

Comment: Believe me, you definitely don't need `NSMutableArray`. Once again, the `var` keyword makes any Swift collection type (`Array`, `Dictionary`) mutable. If you need reference types use classes rather than structs

Comment: it doesnt let me use the normal `var post: [Post] = []` @vadian

Comment: @Jiyar What doesn't let you? Assuming you actually have a class or struct named `Post` then that line is perfectly fine.

Comment: `[Post]` is just an example if there is a custom class or struct `Post`

Comment: @vadian the thing is iam using a dictionary to upload the post and not a struct or a class

Comment: @vadian cant i just make the searchbar work without changing my NSMutableArray?

Comment: @Jiyar It would really help if you update your question with relevant code showing what you actually have and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @rmaddy sense iam using a dictionary to upload the post to firebase and not a struct or a class

Comment: If you are using a dictionary the equivalent Swift array is `[[String:Any]]`. And if you don't want to adopt Swift types and patterns why do you use Swift at all? `NSMutableArray` belongs to Objective-C

Comment: okey now i have added my uploading code and my downloading code @rmaddy

Answer (score -1):

Why not just cast `NSMutableArray` to a Swift array? For safety I recommend using a `guard` statement like so:

`guard let swiftArrayPosts = posts as? [String] else { return }`

Then you can use Swift higher-order functions like `filter` to find the posts you want:

`let filteredPosts = swiftArrayPosts.filter { $0 == "MyQuery" }`

Then assign `filteredPosts` to whatever data source you are using to display them.

Comment: i really have a hard time understanding this like were should i type this? in the `setUpSearchBar` function or just above or would i create a new function thats does this whenever the `user` hits `Search` ?

Comment: Need to see more code to understand what you're talking about.  There is no native `setUpSearchBar` function.  but yes you would want to use whenever the user is typing a query.

Comment: Updated the Question added my uploading clode and my downloading code

Comment: firstly. you need to assign the searchController's search bar to table view header view `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar` do this in your `setUpSearchBarFunction`

Comment: The searchbar is already in the "navigation" bar and is shown whenever The user scrolls to The top of The tableview

Comment: it won't behave properly that way.  That's why your search does not work. You need to assign to table header view

Comment: i did it  and i got this error `Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'`

Comment: If you put `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar` inside the body of your `setUpSearchBar` function you should not see this error

Comment: I think you need to watch or read some more entry-level Swift resources before trying to implement more intermediate features like this.   You seem lack some fundamental understanding of the language

Comment: yes i lack in this language alot but i understans some of it and i did put it in the `setUpSearhBar` but i got that error anyway